# CSS Responsive images with same position

Tags: css

I create one page with bootstrap and add 3 svg images. Now, on desktop is look good, but when I change view on mobile two images disappear. How I can fix this view for mobile?

This is desktop screenshot
[image]

This is mobile when I lose two images
[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-12 row-1 mid">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <img class="img-fluid img-icon icon1" src="img/icon/web-dizajn.svg" alt="Potrebna vam je pomoc oko izrade web sajta?">
    <img class="img-fluid img-icon icon2" src="img/icon/graficki-dizajn.svg" alt="Potrebna vam je pomoc oko izrade web sajta?">
    <img class="img-fluid img-icon icon3" src="img/icon/web-hosting.svg" alt="Potrebna vam je pomoc oko izrade web sajta?">
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <h4>Web Dizajn</h4>
    <p></p>
    <p>
      <a href="#">Pročitaj više</a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-1 {
    display: flex;
}
.mid {
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff 0, #ffffff 100%);
    border-radius: 35px;
    padding: 50px;
    border: 15px solid #f7f7f7;
}
.img-fluid {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.img-icon {
    width: 50%;
}
.icon1 { padding:0px; }
.icon2 { position: absolute; left: 0; padding:75px; top:50px; }
.icon3 { position: absolute; right: 0; padding:75px; top:50px; }
```

Comment: My assumption is that it has to do with the absolute positioning...can you demo?

Comment: Can you please provide a demo with accessible images ?

Comment: Yes this is live demo: [LIVE WEBSITE](https://alexaidzuo.github.io/idizajnercom/)

Answer (score 1):

When your viewport size is < 992px, the icon size with padding is 150px. Since you have a padding of 75px, the left and right padding "eat up" the whole width space (75 + 75 = 150), which leaves no room to show the actual image. You need to reduce the padding with a CSS media query, like this:

```
@media (max-width: 991px) {
    .icon2 { position: absolute; left: 0; padding:35px; top:50px; }
    .icon3 { position: absolute; left: 0; padding:35px; top:50px; }
}
```

And maybe change the top value as well. Experiment with different values until you get the exact look you're aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

From your live demo, seems like you're using padding to reduce size of your svn image. Problem is padding is larger than container, causing image having inside width and height 0. Consider using percent width and height like your first image or use media queries to reduce padding values on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

When you decrease the screen size you will need to edit the css for .icon2 and .icon3 so that the padding doesn't result in the image disappearing so that there is no space for the image to display.

Try this

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
  .icon2 {
    padding:10px;
    top:20px;
  }
  .icon3 {
    padding:10px;
    top:20px;
  }
}
```

992px is the biggest width before the large screen changes. The position and left will be same throughout.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the positions for icon2 and icon3 in mobile resolution and try remove the padding for these icons. If you post a plunker it will be helpful to give the exact solution.